# Embedding a D3 graph in static HTML without installing wrappers or packages

Tags: node.js, d3.js, next.js

I have a `next.js` (react) application and I wanted to embed a few graphs that were written as static files (i.e., HTML, CSS, JS). How can I do that?

Example Graph: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4061961

I found some answers around `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but not sure how this applies as I am new to `nextjs`.

Answer (score 1):

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` will set `HTML` directly. Its mostly used to add libraries such as facebook, hotjar,... to your app. when using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` be careful please read this [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) and this [one](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html).
you can add script to your `_document.js` file. Something like:

```
  <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `// your html here`,
            }}
          />
```